# Java: grabbing second highest

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the second highest number in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615712/finding-the-second-highest-number-in-array)

I have this,

```
       for(int i=0;i<Dices.length;i++){
        if( Dices[i].getValue() > highest ){
            highest = Dices[i].getValue();
        }
       }
```

to get highest value. I now want to get the second highest, how can I do it? Cant i take advantage of this highest variable for getting the second highest?

Comment: You have a defined value for highest? Why don't you then have a defined value for second highest? Put them in a ArrayList sort them ascending, loop through them and store previous value.

Comment: You have one `die` and some `dice` not `dices`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this in *O(n)* speed:

```
// first, second, d0, d1, di all typed by whatever getValue() returns...
// This assumes you have at least two elements in your Dices array

d0 = Dices[0].getValue();
d1 = Dices[1].getValue();
if (d0 > d1) {
    first=d0;
    second=d1;
} else {
    first=d1;
    second=d0;
}

for (int i = 2; i < Dices.length; i++) {
    di = Dices[i].getValue();
    if (di > first) {
        second = first;
        first = di;
    } else if (di > second)
        second = di;
}
```

Comment: @Andy great solution! This is exactly the thing I was considering when I commented on @Sean's answer.

Comment: @Andy, +1 for implementing the correct solution

Comment: +1 for efficiency, although you could say that this is a classic case of premature optimization. Now please let's have the 3 largest values :-)

Comment: @Sean I'm to lazy to spit out an answer for the top three values.  I'd use your solution for that, unless I really needed speed.

Comment: @Andy I wasn't seriously asking for one, I just pointed out the weakness of your answer. But given an array with more than a million entries, I'd also use your answer.

Answer (score 2):

- [Sort the array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) using a custom
  [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) ([make a copy of the array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29)
  if you can't sort the original)
- Pick the last-but-one item of the sorted array:

  ```
  // hopefully you have checked in advance that there is more than one item
  return sortedDices[sortedDices.length-2];
  ```

Comment: Since we're just talking about the two highest do you necessarily have to sort the entire array? I'm just trying to think of logic where you traverse the array only once. I do agree that sorting the array is the best solution just trying to think outside of the box here.

Comment: @Ryan which is the best depends on the situation. Mine is the most usable and manageable, Andy's is the most efficient (at least for large arrays)