# find second and third maximum element array java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max

I have to find 1st, 2nd, and 3rd largest array. I know I could simply sort it and return array[0], array[1], array[3]. But the problem is, i need the index, not the value.
For example if i have `float[] listx={8.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 9.0}` it should return 4, 0, and 3.

Here's the code I have but it doesn't work:

```
//declaration max1-3        
public void maxar (float[] listx){

    float maxel1=0;
    float maxel2=0;
    float maxel3=0;

    for (int i=0; i<listx.length; i++){
        if(maxel1<listx[i])
        {maxel1=listx[i];
        max1=i;
        }
    }
    listx[max1]=0; //to exclude this one in nextsearch

    for (int j=0; j<listx.length; j++){
        if(listx[j]>maxel2)
        {maxel2=listx[j];
        max2=j;
        }
    }
    listx[max2]=0;

    for (int k=0; k<listx.length; k++){
        if(listx[k]>maxel3)
        {maxel3=listx[k];
        max3=k;
        }
    }
}
```

I get max1 right but after that all the elements turns to 0. hence max2 and max3 become 0. Please suggest me what is wrong with this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615712/finding-the-second-highest-number-in-array) post

Answer (score 2):

You can find the three elements using a single loop, and you don't need to modify the array.

When you come across a new largest element, you need to shift the previous largest and the previous second-largest down by one position.

Similarly, when you find a new second-largest element, you need to shift `maxel2` into `maxel3`.

Instead of using the three variables, you might want to employ an array. This will enable you to streamline the logic, and make it easy to generalize to `k` largest elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make 3 passes over array: on first pass find value and 1st index of maximum element `M1`, on second pass find value and 1st index of maximum element `M2` which is lesser than `M1` and on third pass find value/1st index `M3 < M2`.

Comment: 3 passes is overkill. Only one pass is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work :)

```
  public class Array
    {
  public void getMax( double ar[] )
   {
    double max1 = ar[0]; // Assume the first
    double max2 = ar[0]; // element in the array
    double max3 = ar[0]; // is the maximum element.
    int ZERO = 0; 
     // Variable to store inside it the index of the max value to set it to zero.

    for( int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++ )
    {
        if( ar[i] >= max1)
        {
            max1 = ar[i];
            ZERO = i;
        }
    }

    ar[ZERO] = 0; // Set the index contains the 1st max to ZERO.

    for( int j = 0; j < ar.length; j++ )
    {
        if( ar[j] >= max2 )
        {
            max2 = ar[j];
            ZERO = j;
        }
    }

    ar[ZERO] = 0; // Set the index contains the 2st max to ZERO.

    for( int k = 0; k < ar.length; k++ )
    {
        if( ar[k] >= max3 )
        {
            max3 = ar[k];
            ZERO = k;
        }
    }

            System.out.println("1st max:" + max1 + ", 2nd: " +max2 + ",3rd: "+ max3);                              
   }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Creating an object from the class Array to be able to use its methods.
    Array array = new Array();
    // Creating an array of type double.
    double a[] = {2.2, 3.4, 5.5, 5.5, 6.6, 5.6};

    array.getMax( a ); // Calling the method that'll find the 1st max, 2nd max, and      and 3rd max.
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a single pass instead of three for optimization. The code below works for me. Note that the code does not assert that `listx` has at least 3 elements. It is up to you to decide what should happen in case it contains only 2 elements or less.

What I like about this code is that it only does one pass over the array, which in its best case would have faster running time compared to doing three passes, with a factor proportionate to the number of elements in `listx`.

Assume *i1*, *i2* and *i3* store the indices of the three greatest elements in `listx`, and *i0* is one of *i1, i2* and *i3* that points to the smallest element. In the beginning, *i1 = i2 = i3* because we haven't found the largest elements yet. So let *i0 = i1*. If we find a new index *j* such that that `listx[j] > listx[i0]`, we set *i0 = j*, replacing that old index with an index that leads to a greater element. Then we find the index among *i1, i2* and *i3* that now leads to the smallest element of out the three, so that we can safely discard *that* one in case a new large element comes along.

**Note**: This code is in C, so translate it to Java if you want to use it. I made sure to use similar syntax to make that easier. (I wrote it in C because I lacked a Java testing environment.)

```
void maxar(float listx[], int count) {
    int maxidx[3] = {0};

    /* The index of the 3rd greatest element
     * in listx.
     */
    int max_3rd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (listx[maxidx[max_3rd]] < listx[i]) {
            /* Exchange 3rd greatest element
             * with new greater element.
             */
            maxidx[max_3rd] = i;

            /* Find index of smallest maximum. */
            for (int j = (max_3rd + 1) % 3; j != max_3rd; j = (j + 1) % 3) {
                if (listx[maxidx[j]] < listx[maxidx[max_3rd]]) {
                    max_3rd = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* `maxidx' now contains the indices of
     * the 3 greatest values in `listx'.
     */

    printf("3 maximum elements (unordered):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("index: %2d, element: %f\n", maxidx[i], listx[maxidx[i]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int secondlargest = 0;
        int thirdLargest=0;
        int largest = 0;
        int arr[] = {5,4,3,8,12,95,14,376,37,2,73};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (largest < arr[i]) {
                secondlargest = largest;
                largest = arr[i];
            }
            if (secondlargest < arr[i] && largest != arr[i])
                secondlargest = arr[i];
            if(thirdLargest<arr[i] && secondlargest!=arr[i] && largest!=arr[i] && thirdLargest<largest && thirdLargest<secondlargest)
                thirdLargest =arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Largest number is: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Second Largest number is: " + secondlargest);
        System.out.println("third Largest number is: " + thirdLargest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def third_mar_array(arr):
    max1=0
    max2=0
    max3=0
    for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
         if max1<arr[i]:
             max1=arr[i]
             max_in1=i
    arr[max_in1]=0
    for j in range(0,len(arr)-1):
         if max2<arr[j]:
             max2=arr[j]
             max_in2=j
    arr[max_in2]=0
    for k in range(0,len(arr)-1):
         if max3<arr[k]:
             max3=arr[k]
             max_in3=k
    #arr[max_in3]=0
    return max3

n=[5,6,7,3,2,1]

f=first_array(n)
print f
```

Comment: Please, add a description of the solution you are proposing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcase = sc.nextInt();

        while (testcase-- > 0) {
            int sizeOfArray = sc.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[sizeOfArray];
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            int max1, max2, max3;
            max1 = 0;
            max2 = 0;
            max3 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > max1) {
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = max1;
                    max1 = arr[i];
                }
                else if (arr[i] > max2) {
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = arr[i];
                }
                else if (arr[i] > max3) {
                    max3 = arr[i];
                }
            }

            System.out.println(max1 + " " + max2 + " " + max3);
        }
    }
}
```