# How to find second highest number in array in java

Tags: java

I want to find second highest number in array in java.
I tied to solve problem from this code.

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Random r=new Random();
        int max=0;
        int secondMax = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.print("Input an integer : ");
            int num = input.nextInt();

            if (num>max)
            {   
                secondMax=max;
                max=num;
            }       

        }

        System.out.println("Max number is : "+max);
        System.out.println("Second Max number is : "+secondMax);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the second highest number in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615712/finding-the-second-highest-number-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find the max and second values while populating the array. Try removing

```
        if (num>max)
        {   
            secondMax=max;
            max=num;
        }
```

from the for loop. Then add a separate (not nested) for loop to search the array:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if (input[i] > max){
        secondMax = max;
        max = input[i];
      }

      if ((input[i] < max) && (input[i] > secondMax))
        secondMax = input[i];
    }
```

Comment: Actually this is working only for the positive number.not working for negative numbers...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int []numbers=new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i <10 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Input an integer: ");
             numbers[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        int max=0;
        int secondHighest=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {       
            if (numbers[i]>max)
            {
                secondHighest=max;
                max=numbers[i];
            }
            if (numbers[i]<max && numbers[i]>=secondHighest )
            {
                secondHighest=numbers[i];
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Max number is : "+max);
        System.out.println("Second highest number is : "+secondHighest);        
    }

}
```