# Two biggest of array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question it seems easy but i can not solve it Array of n integers is given. Find the two biggest elements in array. I found the first one can not find second one. Please help me to find the second one.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    int maks=a[0];
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        if(a[i]>maks) {
            maks=a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << maks;
}
```

Comment: need to find 2 biggest element in array C++.Given 5 element in array

Comment: You don't even need an array to do this, just saying.

Comment: Note: Variable-length arrays [are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367473/create-an-array-when-the-size-is-a-variable-not-a-constant/57367539#57367539).

Comment: Answer is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412779/4850111)

Comment: yes that worked actually a lot and made the code clear for me thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet to find second biggest element in a array,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int top2element[2];
    if (a[0] > a[1]) {
        top2element[0] = a[0];
        top2element[1] = a[1];
    }
    else {
        top2element[1] = a[0];
        top2element[0] = a[1];
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] > top2element[0])
        {

            top2element[1] = top2element[0];
            top2element[0] = a[i];
        }
        else if (a[i] > top2element[1]) {
            top2element[1]= a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << top2element[0]<<endl;//biggest
    cout << top2element[1];//second biggest

    delete a;
}
```

Note: allocate memory dynamically if input stream is of unknown size